# What does this (electrical) value mean on my washing machine's back?

Tags: electrical, washing-machine

The electrical parameters of my washing machine are printed on the back. Among them there is a value for amperage:

[image]

It says 10A but I don't know if that means that I need a fuse of minimum 10A or the washing machine drains a maximum of 10A and my fuse needs to be bigger (but not equal) than 10A to accommodate for that.

So what does 10A mean for a washing machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol to the left is the [IEEE](http://www.ieee.org/index.html) (Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers) symbol for a fuse, so it's telling you you need a 10A fuse.  A 10A fuse will allow a maximum sustained current of 10A; anything above that will cause the fuse to blow -- how quickly it does will depend on the current that is passing through the fuse.

See the Wikipedia page for [electrical fuses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuse_%28electrical%29) for more information

Comment: A minimum of 10A?

Comment: @bug See my edit

Comment: Keep in mind that this rating should take into account the 80% "working load limit" on electrical circuits; an appliance like a dryer rated for a dedicated 220VAC10A circuit should actually draw less than 1760W while running, though the breaker won't trip until current exceeds 2200W.